# Using IIS 7.5 as development server with VS2010.Web service failing

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, web-services, iis-7.5

I have a website with few .aspx pages and few .asmx services.It is working perfectly with the built in Visual Studio  web server.I wanted to test it in Local IIS server 7.5 before moving it into production. But there are some issues.

When running the website it is directing to the login page( http/localhost/Login.aspx), 
but after clicking the login button it is not taking to the home page. I found that the login service(asmx) fails .I'm using  Jquery .Ajax and data type is json for calling the method in the webservice(.asmx)

- My settings

1) In IIS Manager, I created a folder under sites and pointed to the  physical Location of project files.

2) In Visual Studio,solution explorer-->property pages--> start options-->
I Choose **custom server** and Base URL: http//localhost.(There is no Local IIS server option to choose.)

Here the error details I'm getting in chrome/Inspect element.

(Request URL:http://localhost/ReportDataservice.asmx/ProcessLogin
Request Method:POST   Status Code:500 Internal Server Error)

Do I need to do any change IIS 7.5 settings or VS environment? It is working perfectly with built in VS server.

Thanks!

Mathew

Comment: What message are you getting if you put this URL http://localhost/ReportDataservice.asmx directly in browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resolved after I updated the patch for Visual studio 2010 for IIS 7.5.The web services are working fine after that.